# Grunt-string-replace using an object of key-value pairs

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-string-replace

I started using grunt in my build process. In `package.json` I include variables to be replaced this way:

```json
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "variableToReplace":{
    "var1":"var1_replacement",
    "var2":"var2_replacement"
  },
  ...
}
```

However, I do not know how to use this `variableToReplace` in `Gruntfile.js` so that it will automatically look up all properties then replace them with the corresponding values. Is it possible using Grunt?

```js
'string-replace': {
  dist: {
    files: {
      //A list of files
    },
    options: {
      //What to put here?
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Revised Answer (after comment)

> ... Is there anyway to loop through the key-value pair of `variableToReplace` and replace, for example, `var1` with `var1_replacement`.

Yes, this can be achieved by utilizing a [Custom Task](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks). The custom task should perform the following:

1. Read the `variableToReplace` object from `package.json`.
2. Dynamically build the `options.replacements` array.
3. Configure/set the `option.replacements` array using [`grunt.config.set`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config.set)
4. Then finally run the task using [`grunt.task.run`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.run).

The following `Gruntfile.js` demonstrates this solution:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-string-replace');

  grunt.initConfig({

    'string-replace': {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'src/',
          src: '**/*.css',
          dest: 'dist/'
        }],
        options: {
          replacements: [] // <-- Intentionally empty and will be dynamically
                           //     configured via `configAndRunStringReplace`.
        }
      }
    }
  });

  /**
   *  Helper task to dynamically configure the Array of Objects for the
   * `options.replacements` property in the `dist` target of the `string-replace`
   *  task. Each property name of the `variableToReplace` Object (found in
   * `package.json`) is set as the search string, and it's respective value
   *  is set as the replacement value.
   */
  grunt.registerTask('configAndRunStringReplace', function () {

    // 1. Read the `variableToReplace` object from `package.json`.
    var replacements = grunt.file.readJSON('package.json').variableToReplace,
      config = [];

    // 2. Dynamically build the `options.replacements` array.
    for (key in replacements) {
      config.push({
        pattern: new RegExp(key, 'g'),
        replacement: replacements[key]
      });
    }

    // 3. Configure the option.replacements values.
    grunt.config.set('string-replace.dist.options.replacements', config);

    // 4. Run the task.
    grunt.task.run('string-replace:dist');
  });

  // Note: In the `default` Task we add the `configAndRunStringReplace`
  // task to the taskList array instead of `string-replace`.
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['configAndRunStringReplace']);
}
```

**Important note regarding Regular Expressions:**

The [docs](https://github.com/eruizdechavez/grunt-string-replace#notes) for `grunt-string-replace` states:

> *If the pattern is a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced...*

To ensure that multiple instances of the search/find string are matched and replaced the `configAndRunStringReplace` custom task utilizes a Regular Expression with the [global `g` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global).

So, any instances of the following regex special characters:

```
\ ^ $ * + ? . ( ) | { } [ ]
```

which may be used in a search word (i.e. as a key/property name in your `package.json`) will need to be escaped. The typical way to escape these characters in a Regex is to add a backslash `\` before the character (E.g. `\?` or `\+` etc..). However, because you're using key/property names in JSON to define your search word. You'll need to double escape any of the previously mentioned characters to ensure your JSON remains valid. For Example:

Lets say you wanted to replace question marks (`?`) with exclamation marks (`!`). Instead of defining those rules in `package.json` like this:

```json
...
"variableToReplace":{
  "?": "!"
},
...
```

Or like this:

```json
...
"variableToReplace":{
  "\?": "!"
},
...
```

You'll need to do this (i.e. use double escapes `\\`):

```json
...
"variableToReplace":{
  "\\?": "!"
},
...
```

---

#### Original Answer

The following contrived example shows how this can be achieved:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-string-replace');

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'), // 1. Read the package.json file.

    'string-replace': {
      dist: {
        files: {
          'dist/': ['src/css/**/*.css'],
        },
        options: {
          replacements: [{
            // 2. Use grunt templates to reference the properties in package.json
            pattern: '<%= pkg.variableToReplace.var1 %>',
            replacement: '<%= pkg.variableToReplace.var2 %>',
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['string-replace']);

}
```

**Notes**

1. Add `pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')` to the `grunt.initConfig()` section of your `Gruntfile.js`. This will parse the JSON data stored in `package.json`.
2. Use [grunt templates](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.template) to access the properties of `package.json`. The standard JavaScript dot notation is used to access the property values, (e.g. `pkg.variableToReplace.var1`), and is wrapped in a leading `<%=` and trailing `%>`
3. Using the contrived `Gruntfile.js` configuration above with your the `package.json` data (as described in your question). The following would occur:

   - Any instances of the string `var1_replacement` found in any of the `.css` files stored in the `src/css/` directory will be replaced with the string `var2_replacement`.
   - The resultant files will be saved to the `dist/` directory.

Comment: But by your code, var1 will be replaced by var2. Is there anyway to loop through the key-value pair of variableToReplace and replace, for example, var1 with var1_replacement

Comment: Sorry for the late confirm update. It was really excellent answer